# Use of could vs. can and even

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs, word-difference

Before the following sentence I state that "we could train the "XX" function by using certain idea in an optimization problem for a model."
Then I want to say:

> Moreover, we **could** also train, by using a same idea or new ideas, the
>   "YY" function and bring in different models in one optimization
>   problem. In this way I suppose we shall have a better result, **even**.

**Question 1**: Should I use *could* or *can*? (Solved)
 
**Question 2**: Do I use *even* correctly?
**Question 3**: How may I write this sentence better...? I feel weird when I read it...

Comment: @FumbleFingers ah sorry. Could or can is just a btw question. My main question is 2 and 3.

Comment: Moreover, we could also train, by using **the** same idea [whatever that idea may be] or new ideas, the "YY" function and bring (omitted 'in') different models in one optimization problem. (Omitted 'in') This way, I suppose we shall even have a better result. (moved even) - just a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry - but perhaps you should have asked two questions. Personally I'd say your position for ***even*** sounds klunky. I'd move it to *...an **even** better result*. I'd also move *by using a same idea or new ideas* to before *we could also train*, becauise you've got too much verbiage between the verb *(train)* and the object *(the "XX" function)*. But this is all "writing style advice", probably Off Topic.

Comment: @shin: I think although moving ***even*** so it modifies ***have*** rather than ***better*** is "credible", it carries relatively unlikely implications. We'd have to assume there's *also* some other (obvious, but unstated) advantage to the "training" for that placement, whereas if ***even*** comes immediately before ***better*** we only need to assume that previous results (without the training) were already relatively good (so they can become *even better*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thank you for adding that essential point. I didn't assume as I do not know the exact context (I'm afraid that modifying better may sound a bit 'pushy', than the other? I don't know if OP wants to have it that way)

Comment: Thx yours comment! I agree with @FumbleFingers since I only would generally say the result would be better. But shin, thx a lot for your answer!

Comment: You could write: [I think] this may yield an even better result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding *can/could*:

*Could* is used to express a conditional statement.  With *could*, you are saying *if condition x, then i am able to y*.  A full conditional statement will have two clauses, one containing *could* and the other expressing the condition - either may be omitted if context supplied that information earlier, though.

*Can* just means *is able to* and doesn't necessarily have to be connected with a condition, though it often is.  (As an aside, *could* can also be the past tense form of *can*.)

Some examples to illustrate:

> I could make more money if I go to school and get a degree. (Conditional statement.)
>
> I can make more money by getting a degree from a school. (Expresses a conditional idea IMHO but not really a conditional statement.)

And of course you'll hear in real-life speech people using these two interchangeably.

In your sentence I would use *can* because you don't have a second clause that expresses a condition, to me you are saying *we can do by using {object}* more than *we could do X if {clause}*.

---

Regarding *even*:

> In this way I suppose we shall have a better result, even.

*Even* can be an adverb and like most adverbs it is flexible where it can be placed.  However, where you have it, it seems to convey "additional" because it seems to modify the entire clause "In this way I suppose we shall have a better result." Similar to this:

> He gave me 500 dollars.  I can buy food, and talk to a repair person about fixing my windows, even.

Here, *food* is the primary benefit, and *clothes* is an additional "side" benefit.  *Even* would seem weird if I did not mention an initial benefit, unless context/previous conversation filled in the blanks.  Unless I'm missing something there seems to be only one "benefit" provided in your sentence (unless "different optimization models" is that other benefit.)

Comment: We use *could* for reasons besides expressing conditionality. I could use it to express possibility. Could I use it to ask a question, even? Yes!